# Blank page in Polymer

Tags: polymer

I am newbie for polymer. I just tried to add but getting blank screen. Did I missed any script or something?

Head

```
<script src="bower_components/polymer/polymer.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-drawer-panel/core-drawer-panel.html">
```

body

```
   <core-drawer-panel transition id="core_drawer_panel" touch-action>
        <section id="section" drawer></section>
        <section id="section1" main></section>
    </core-drawer-panel>
    <script>

        Polymer({
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: How are you loading the page? are you directly running the HTML page from file explorer? or are you running it in a server

Comment: Thanks @Derek Its running in server. I found my mistake is I should include polymer/polymer.html instead of polymer/polymer.js and I missed styles.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is exactly how it should be.

Look in your inspector and you will see that there is a core-drawer-panel element with two section's. The core-drawer-panel doesn't have any visual and is just a container that holds your sub components.

Basically you need to put something in the sections to see something in the browser :)

Add the following to your code:

```
<style>
 core-drawer-panel /deep/ section { 
  border:1px solid red;
 }
</style>
```

This will visually highlight the sections.

Comment: Thanks @Andy It works. I did another mistake is I should include polymer/polymer.html instead of polymer/polymer.js

Comment: @BlueBells In addition, you don't need the webcomponentsjs included on the latest versions of Polymer.  You would use the `polymer.html` reference on your start page (most likely your `index.html` which isn't a web component.  If @andy 's answer solves your issue, you should mark it as the answer...